# Why React Testing Library only works with ternary conditional rendering?

Tags: reactjs, class, conditional-statements, react-functional-component, ternary

I'm trying to do conditional rendering in react following [its docs instructions](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

I'm doing a Triomphe card game for a school project and i have this condition, if my cards deck already has a triomphe card, i need to render a paragraph saying to the user that his can have only one card of that type and he already have it on his deck

to do this a have the following component inside my class component that render the form to add cards to the game.

```
function HandleTrunfo(props) {
  if (props.hasTrunfo) {
    return (
      <p>
        You already have a triomphe card on your deck
      </p>);
  }
  return (
    <label htmlFor="cardTrunfo">
      Super Trunfo:
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="cardTrunfo"
        data-testid="trunfo-input"
        value={ props.cardTrunfo }
        onChange={ props.onInputChange }
        checked={ props.cardTrunfo }
      />
    </label>
  );
}
```

then a call it on the `render()` like this:

```
<HandleTrunfo { ...this.props } />
```

but my tests fail when i do this way

```
  33 |     userEvent.click(saveBtn);
  34 |
> 35 |     const expectedMsg = screen.getByText(/You already have a triomphe card on your deck/i);
     |                                ^
  36 |     expect(expectedMsg).toBeInTheDocument();
  37 |     expect(checkboxTrunfo).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  38 |   });
```

But when doing ternary it works, and all tests succeed:

```
{ hasTrunfo ? <p>You already have a triomphe card on your deck</p>
          : (
            <label htmlFor="cardTrunfo">
              Super Trunfo:
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="cardTrunfo"
                data-testid="trunfo-input"
                value={ cardTrunfo }
                onChange={ onInputChange }
                checked={ cardTrunfo }
              />
            </label>)}
```

I would like to figure it out what is the difference and what is occurring in witch situattion.

PS. I'm doing using class instead functional because its a school requirement (I don't know if its a problem...).

Comment: Can you provide the whole class code? I want to see how you pass the props to HandleInfoTrun and whole flow of data, thanks

Comment: Hello @LironShirazi, how u doing?  here's my full project on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-rgb-n9th8